# Unable click href with Puppeteer

Tags: typescript, puppeteer

I have to click on

```
<a href="javascript:OnNextItem('0');"><img src="../Common/Images/nextitem.gif" border="0" alt="Next item" title="Next item"></a>
```

with Puppetteer.

In Typescript, if I use

```
await page.click('a[href="javascript:OnNextItem("0")"');
```

at runtime I have got the error:

> "Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on >'Document': 'a[href="javascript:OnNextItem("0")"' is not a valid >selector.
>      at **puppeteer_evaluation_script**:1:33"

Where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `javascript:OnNextItem("0")` is probably not the same as `javascript:OnNextItem('0')`. Try using single quotes and escaping as necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `page.click('a[href="javascript:OnNextItem("0")"')` with `page.click('a[href="javascript:OnNextItem('0')"')` (single quotes)

If this dont work try out this workaround

```
const selector = 'input[href="javascript:OnNextItem('0');"]';

// does not work
await page.click(selector); 

// does work
await page.evaluate((selector) => document.querySelector(selector).click(), selector);
```